# Rails app super slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

My Rails app has become very slow at responding (in development only as it's not live yet). I'm really not sure why but I can tell you a few things about it.

I do have the asset pipeline running but hardly use it as I have a gulp workflow setup. All styles and scripts and compiled and minified and served from the public folder.

I have a page which outputs items of a collection at a time each one using the same partial as a template and these are paginated so 25 are shown at a time. I have `remote: true` set on my pagination links. It all works and the next 25 items replace the existing set but it's so slow. It does it's request and I see the queries and requests in the terminal and it does it's rendering but then I see it requesting the photograph of each item one after another and I think this is slowing it down but i'm sure it was never this slow previously. I'm not sure if this is the full problem but it could be contributing. I used to have all the items photos on S3 and it called them from there but to enable me to develop offline I moved them all into the app locally. Could this be slowing it down?

Is there anything you think could be slowing my app down that you could recommend I look at or post on here to help solve it?

Here's the console output for one request on a problematic page: https://gist.github.com/rctneil/4a835ae6bbbc46498160

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific... Can you post the trace of one request and point out, which parts are slow in your opinion?

Comment: Post a log of a complete request.  It may show some hints

Comment: @Swards I've added a link to the console output of a request.

Comment: `theme_parks/index.html.erb` looks *crazy* slow. What are you doing in there? Examine your log for the longest execution times and dig into those files to see what's going on. A simple approach is to start deleting things until the page speeds up, then restore functionality bit by bit until you find the line or lines that's slowing things down. This is easy to manage if you're using a version control system, which hopefully you are.

Comment: @tadman I've updated the gist with my controller file and it's associated methods. I spent hours last night trying to track it down but no luck. I did optimise a few bits but didn't seem to help.

Comment: It's specifically in the `erb` file. I don't know what you're doing there, but it appears to be super slow.

Comment: @tadman Hmmm, I've added some of the views and partials related to this request.

Comment: The most common cause of this is out of control database queries, geometrically bad algorithms where increasing data sets in size linearly results in an exponential slow-down, or both. The best plan is to comment out things aggressively until you get your performance back, then systematically narrow it down to the trouble spots. There's a lot of code there that could be slow, but I can't tell at a glance.

Comment: @tadman Ok. Thanks. I'll take a deeper dive into it.